# Iphone:Help in understanding Crash reports

Tags: iphone, ios4, appcelerator, crash-reports

I recently worked on app which got crashed. I made this app by using Appcelerator tool which let you write apps in Javascript. The code which apple pointed and the crash report is given below:

It;s crashing on iPhone 4 running iOS 4.2.1.(as reported by Apple). Relevant files are given below:

Code: http://pastie.org/1543760

Crash Report: http://pastie.org/1542144

I am just not being able to understand it.

Help me out!

Thanks

Comment: the lesson here? Dont use appcelerator! Its a shoddy tool made to allow people to cut corners on creating apps. I know people who tried it and the apps they made were riddled with bugs and volatile. Learn objective c and do it properly.

Comment: Aside from the `objc_exception_throw` in the crash log, indicating an exception being thrown, I can't make much out of this log. If you were developing this using standard Cocoa, you would be able to see symbolicated method calls in here, but I have no idea how to debug Appcelerator-generated binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have same issue, My app is rejected by apple by saying

> 2.1  Apps that crash will be rejected

And they give a crash report, I search and find how to read a crash report.
I think this may help you.

Drag the crash report to Xcode>Window>organizer>Device logs
This will show the crash report as a more readable form. In it some of your app function show as memory locations. The following line help you to find the line of error,

Steps to analyze crash report from apple:

1. Copy the release .app file which was pushed to the appstore, the .dSYM file that was created at the time of release and the crash report receive from APPLE into a FOLDER.
2. OPEN terminal application and go to the folder created above (using CD command)
3. `atos -arch armv7  -o '<your .app file name here>'/'<.dSYM filename here>' <memory location in the crash report where the crash occured>`. The memory location should be the one at which the app crashed as per the report.

Example for Foo.app: `atos -arch armv7  -o 'Foo.app'/'Foo' 0x0003b508`

This would show you the exact line, method name which resulted in crash.

Comment: Will this give the line number of the JS code, or will it give the line number of the Objective-C code.